# при прочтении csv файла выдает ошибку, что якобы нет такого такого абзаца. ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Unique Key'

Tags: pandas, csv

при выполнении кода выдает эту ошибку
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': 'Unique Key'

сам же код

```
import pandas as pd

# Загрузка данных из CSV файла
fixed_df = pd.read_csv('Complaint_data.csv',  # Путь к файлу
                       sep='///',      # Разделитель в файле
                       encoding='utf-8',  # Кодировка
                       parse_dates=['Unique Key'],  # Парсинг столбца с датами
                       dayfirst=True,         # Формат даты - день-месяц-год
                       index_col='Unique Key')      # Использование столбца с датами как индекса
```

такой файл есть, он лежит в одной папке с этим питон-файлом в котором код прописан и такой абзац там тоже есть

Comment: Можно увидеть CSV? Разделитель `sep='///'` выглядит странно

Comment: Под абзацем вы имеете в виду столбец? Это вообще-то разные вещи. Покажите содержимое файла, хотя бы первых несколько строк.

Comment: да, там сеп не верный был, еще теперь ругается на разны типы данных в файле